# Prove Variable Equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Being $ p, q, r, s, t \in \mathbb {R} ^ * _ {+} $ and knowing that

$\begin{cases}
p^2+pq+q^2=s^2\\
q^2+qr+r^2=t^2 \\
r^2+rp+p^2=s^2-st+t^2\\
  \end{cases}$

Prove that

$\frac{s^2-st+t^2}{s^2t^2}=\frac{r^2}{q^2t^2}+\frac{p^2}{q^2s^2}-\frac{pr}{q^2ts}$

What I tried: I was trying the obvious, he already gives the numerator, $s ^ 2 $ and $ t ^ 2,$ so theoretically the only job was to make the product.

I noticed that it gives some things like: $ (a + b) ^ 2-ab $, or $(a-b) ^ 2 + ab$ too, but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

$$s^2+t^2-(s^2-st+t^2)=?$$

We already have $$s^2+t^2=?$$

Just replace the values of $$s^2+t^2,st$$

Comment: It would not be more interesting to use that $ s ^ 2 + t ^ 2 = p ^ 2 + 2q ^ 2 + qr + pq + r ^ 2 $ or that $ s ^ 2 + t ^ 2 = r ^ 2 + rp + p ^ 2 + st?$

Comment: @Hermes, Let me check